How to capture exit code of subshell (while in pipe)
somefile contains this:
aaa
bbb
ccc

This is the subshell which can exit before completing all iterations. In my particular case is while but it could be for or until:
cat "somefile" | while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [ "$line" = "bbb" ]
  then
    exit 2
  fi
done
exit_code="$?"
if [ "$exit_code" -ne 0 ]
then
  exit
fi
echo "I'm here"

The issue is that the last line I'm here is printed. My intention is to exit completely to terminal. However I'm not sure if that's correct and will works with all shells. Is that even POSIX? Any mention about how this has to work in POSIX?
I've asked several AI engines and each one comes with a different answer:

Copilot: says that the exit_code will be always 0, because that's the exit code of cat. Could be any other command.
ChatGPT: says the exit_code will the the number after exit, like here 2, because it propagates.
Gemini: says the exit_code will be always 0, because $? gets the exit code of the last instruction, which is done and is always 0.

Any help here? I've tried in bash and it detects the exit code, but not sure if that's some specific bash configuration (like pipefail or  or it's the way it works with any shell (for example in UNIX as well).

You may want to read Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice? and Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells and Understanding "IFS= read -r line" and Why is printf better than echo?

@StéphaneChazelas thanks for the tips, but that doesn't address my concern about the exit codes.

What's the value of the variable $somefile in your script?  If it's th name of the file that you show, then I can't get your script to print I'm here with ash, bash, zsh or dash.

@Kusalananda it's a file but could be a shell variable with several lines, for example the result of a log file.

Can you show exactly how you run your script?

@Kusalananda something simple like sh ./script

According to POSIX:

the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline.

The last command is the while loop. The exit status of a while loop is always 0, unless the shell running it exits without completing the loop.
All sh-like shells behave like this.1
Part of the behavior depends on the shell, however. Most sh-like shells, including the classic Bourne shell, bash, dash and mksh, run each side of the pipe in a subshell. If exit 2 is reached, it exits the subshell for the right-hand side of the pipe, so the line exit_code="$?" sets exit_code to 2. In ATT ksh and zsh, the right-hand side of a pipe is executed in the main shell, so if exit 2 is reached, the whole script exits with the status 2 and the line exit_code="$?" is never executed.
The only way echo "I'm here" can be reached is if the file does not contain a line that contains exactly bbb.
If you're working on Windows, make sure your file has Unix line endings, not Windows line endings. Windows line endings consist of the two characters CR LF, whereas Unix line endings are just LF, so Unix tools see Windows lines as containing the expected text plus a CR character.
1 For completeness: some shells can be configured to give the pipe a nonzero status if any of the commands fail by running set -o pipefail. With this configuration, if the while loop returns 0, you get the exit status of cat, which is 0 if the given file can be read.

Note that your link is to the previous edition of the POSIX specification. The text in the latest revision has changed significantly with the introduction of the pipefail option.

Also note the lastpipe option in bash that affects the way the last component of a pipeline is run when non-interactive.

... and if it weren't the WHILE it would be the IF.  if false; then echo false; fi; echo $? outputs 0. @Smeterlink

The exit status of a pipeline is that of the right-most component if the pipefail option¹ is off (default) or that of the right-most component that has a non-zero exit status if pipefail is on.
For example, the exit status of (exit 12) | (exit 5) | (exit 0) will be 0 without pipefail, and 5 with.
Now, in a sh pipeline, it's unspecified by POSIX whether the last (right-most) component of a pipeline runs in a subshell or not, and in practice, it varies with sh implementation.
So, depending on the shell, that exit 2, if run, will either exit the script altogether, or only exit the subshell that runs that while loop. In the latter case, the exit status of the pipeline will then be 2 regardless of whether the pipefail option is on or not.
Here, though you'd do something like:
<somefile awk '{print}; $0 == "bbb" {exit 2}' || exit
echo "I'm here"

That is invoke a text processing utility to do text processing, not hundreds of invocations (assuming hundreds lines input) of inappropriate tools such as read, echo, [.
See also:

Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?
Understanding "IFS= read -r line"
Why is printf better than echo?
Should I care about unnecessary cats?


¹ a ksh extension now found in most sh implementations and specified by POSIX since the 2024 edition of the standard but not found in all implementations yet and in particular, not dash.
